# Embedding fields in all mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents that follows this structure:

```
child: 
    {
    id: int 
    name: string
    age: int
    dob: date
    school: string
    class: string
    }
```

I would like to embed certain fields, into something like this:

```
child:
    {
    id : int
    personalInfo {
        name: string
        age: int
        dob: date
        }
    educationInfo {
        school: string
        class: string
        }
    }
```

How would one go across in doing this in code? I am new to Mongodb, so I apologize if my syntax is incorrect. All of the fields have one-to-one relationships with the child (i.e. one child has one id, one name, one age, one school etc.), so I'm also wondering if embedding is even necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to set the new field `personalInfo` and `educationInfo`, with [`#unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove old fields `age`, `name` etc. Before do it, it would be better to check all those fields exists through [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), here are sample codes as below,

```
> var personfields = [ "name", "age", "dob" ];
> var educationFields = [ "school", "class" ];
> var query = {};
> personFields.forEach(function(k){ query[k] = {$exists: 1}});
> educationFields.forEach(function(k){ query[k] = {$exists: 1}});
> db.collection.find(query).forEach(function(doc){ 
        var personalInfo = {}; 
        var educationInfo = {}; 
        for (var k in doc) { 
            if (personFields.indexOf(k) !== -1){
                personalInfo[k] = doc[k];
            } else if (educationFields.indexOf(k) !== -1) { 
                educationInfo[k] = doc[k];
            } 
        } 
        db.collection.update({_id: doc._id},
                            {$set: {
                                personalInfo: personalInfo, 
                                educationInfo: educationInfo}, 
                             $unset: {'name': '', 
                                      'age': '', 
                                      'dob': '', 
                                      'school': '', 
                                      'class': ''}});
   })
```

Answer (score -1):

It's OK to embed them, that's what document dB's are for. So if you need a migration, you'll basically use mongodb's functions like **update** ,with $set and $unset.

See more here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: That's good to know, but what's the syntax to actually embed the fields?

Comment: Maybe it was a bad answer, but my goal is not to solve the problem but rather help people learn, and how to solve problems themselves. Sorry if I did that the wrong way.